# print master/detail's detail page using Uwp Community Toolkit

Tags: uwp, windows-community-toolkit

I use the [Master/Details view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/controls/masterdetailsview) from the [UWP Community Toolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit) and I am wrapping it in my "custom master/details view". This custom view should be able to print the current `Detail`, so the `DetailsTemplate` property on `MasterDetailsView`. The problem is that I cannot pass a `DataTemplate` to the UWP Toolkit Print Helper like this:

`printHelper.AddFrameworkElementToPrint(NameOfMasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate);`

I tried to make a generic Page which has 2 DependencyProperties: 1) A data model, 2) a DataTemplate. This way I wanted to reuse the DataTemplate I used for the DetailsTemplate. I just passed those to a ContentPresenter:

`<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{Binding MyDataTemplateProp}" Content="{Binding MyModelProp}"`
(I also tried to use DataContext instead of Content).

Results stay the same: A blank page gets printed.

How can one print a `DataTemplate`, populated with a data model?
More specific: how to print a detail page with the UWP Community Toolkit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that I cannot pass a DataTemplate to the UWP Toolkit Print Helper

As your code line showed, you need to add a [`FrameworkElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement) to print. [`DataTempalte`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.datatemplate) is inherit from `FrameworkTemplate` it is not a `FrameworkElement`, it just defined a template that doesn't indicate an area.

> how to print a detail page with the UWP Community Toolkit?

You need to find the element that is responsible for the detail page section. If you check the [`MasterDetailsView`](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/MasterDetailsView/MasterDetailsView.xaml) default template you will find that the detail page is inside a `Grid` named `DetailsPanel`. Try to find the `DetailsPanel` element and pass it to print. For how to find this element you may need to use [`ViualTreeHelper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.media.visualtreehelper).